# Why is GHC emitting incorrect "redundant constraint" warning here?

Tags: haskell, ghc

As per the title I'm curious as to why GHC is emitting a warning about a redundant constraint when its removal makes the code no longer compile.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module Lib where

import           Protolude hiding (from, try)

import           Control.Exception.Safe
import           Database.Esqueleto
import           Database.Persist.TH

newtype PingId =
  PingId Int
  deriving (Enum, Eq, Integral, Num, Ord, Real, Show)

data Ping = Ping
  {
  } deriving (Show)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings] [persistLowerCase|
DbPing sql=pings
|]

pingToDbPing :: Ping -> DbPing
pingToDbPing _ = undefined

dbPingToPing :: DbPing -> Either Text Ping
dbPingToPing _ = undefined

class (PersistEntity a, ToBackendKey SqlBackend a) =>
      FromPersistEntity a b | a -> b where
  fromPersistEntity :: a -> Either Text b

instance FromPersistEntity DbPing Ping where
  fromPersistEntity = dbPingToPing

type family ToKey a :: * where
  ToKey PingId = DbPingId

findById
  :: forall m key record val.
     ( Integral key
     , Key record ~ ToKey key
     , FromPersistEntity record val
     , MonadCatch m
     , MonadIO m
     , MonadReader DbConfig m
     )
  => key -> m (Either Text (Maybe val))
findById key = do
  maybeRetOrErr <-
    try
      (liftIO . evaluate =<<
       runDB
         (select $
          from $ \table -> do
            where_
              (table ^. persistIdField ==. val (toSqlKey . fromIntegral $ key))
            return table))
  case maybeRetOrErr of
    Left (e :: SomeException) -> return . Left . toS . displayException $ e
    Right [] -> return . Right $ Nothing
    Right [ret :: Entity record] ->
      return . fmap Just . fromPersistEntity . entityVal $ ret
    Right _ -> return . Left $ "impossible happened, more than one result"

data DbConfig = DbConfig
  { dbConnectionPool :: ConnectionPool
  }

runDB
  :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader DbConfig m)
  => SqlPersistT IO b -> m b
runDB q = do
  pool <- asks dbConnectionPool
  liftIO $ runSqlPool q pool

test :: IO ()
test = do
  let dbConfig = DbConfig undefined
  flip runReaderT dbConfig $ do
    pingOrErr <- findById (PingId 1)
    print pingOrErr
```

and produces the following warning:

```
/home/ppb/Code/haskell/test/src/Lib.hs:49:1: warning: [-Wredundant-constraints]
    • Redundant constraint: Key record ~ ToKey key
    • In the type signature for:
           findById :: (Integral key, Key record ~ ToKey key,
                        FromPersistEntity record val, MonadCatch m, MonadIO m,
                        MonadReader DbConfig m) =>
                       key -> m (Either Text (Maybe val))
```

and removing the constraint results in the following error:

```
/home/ppb/Code/haskell/test/src/Lib.hs:50:6: error:
    • Could not deduce (FromPersistEntity record0 val)
      from the context: (Integral key,
                         FromPersistEntity record val,
                         MonadCatch m,
                         MonadIO m,
                         MonadReader DbConfig m)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   findById :: (Integral key, FromPersistEntity record val,
                                MonadCatch m, MonadIO m, MonadReader DbConfig m) =>
                               key -> m (Either Text (Maybe val))
        at src/Lib.hs:(50,6)-(57,39)
      The type variable ‘record0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘findById’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      In the type signature:
        findById :: forall m key record val.
                    (Integral key,
                     FromPersistEntity record val,
                     MonadCatch m,
                     MonadIO m,
                     MonadReader DbConfig m) =>
                    key -> m (Either Text (Maybe val))
```

I'm using GHC 8.0.1 and compiling with `-Wall`.

Is there any way I could restructure the code to avoid the warning? Or if that's not possible is there a way to silence the warning on per-function basis, rather than across the whole module with `OPTIONS_GHC`?

---

**EDIT**: compiling with GHC 8.0.2 no longer produces a warning.

Comment: This looks like a bug, and as such you should report it in the bug tracker not StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to say "you should report this bug properly instead of posting it on Stack Overflow". Often you need to ask on Stack Overflow to find out it's a bug rather than your own misunderstanding (and usually it's not a bug). It's fine to say "yes this is a bug, please report it", I just disagree with the "should" phrasing and the implication that it was incorrect to ask about it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate bug of either [#12700](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12700) or [#12702](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12702). One is fixed in 8.0.2, one isn't.

Comment: perhaps you should be allowing ambiguous types. i think the takeaway of #12700 is that it's OK for the warning to be present in situations where the only solution is to enable another extension; in that ticket the extension in question is flexiblecontexts and here (maybe?) it is allowambiguoustypes

Comment: The correction of this defect seems to have regressed in `ghc-8.2.1rc2`.